# Normal map includes different colors

Tags: baking, normal-map

I tried changing ray distance,and using a cage object.But my normal maps are messed up.Can you help me understand what's wrong
[image: Normal Map]
[image: Uv Map]

Can you please check my project file I think this would be the only solution
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YCoYbiYHIZSaD_egg6Wd4x8RXCqtr5By/view?usp=sharing

Comment: maybe you have inverted normals? Sometimes you can't avoid bad baking and in that case you can paint on it with the blue color. But you can share your file so that we can test: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I already checked the nomal faces its seems fine

Comment: I couldn't use the link that you gave me.But I uploaded the project to drive and added the link

Comment: I've tried without cage and with Selected to Active, with an Extrusion of 0.1, and it works rather good: https://zupimages.net/up/21/43/u34p.jpg

Comment: yes, you can check where it happens, it happens when the ray hits some faces that have their normals inverted or you need to increase the Extrusion value to make it work, but it will make other rays fail, so you either need to fix your high-poly topology, or move some faces of your low-poly (which would be a bit tedious imho) or paint this part with a good color

Comment: so something wrong about the model right?what ı suppose to do?

Comment: no it's just that if you really want the image to be 100% good you need for exampl to move some faces of your low-poly etc... check each part that fails and you'll understand why it fails, for example the low poly is too much inside the high-poly, you could increase the Extrusion value but it will make some other parts fail... in my opinion you should just paint the bad part with the correct blue, unless it's very important to keep these parts correct, I may be wrong but it's seems like tiny details

Comment: You can't avoid this kind of problems when an object has a complicated topology. Another solution would be to mix several bakes, not sure it will fix everything here...

Comment: but it will take days .It should be easier right? I can't do this for all of my models.Is this normal workflow? any recommendation?

Comment: my recommandation would be to bake as good as possible and paint were the color is bad, yes it won't create any bumps on the painted parts but I don't see any other solution, except the one I cited: create a second bake... That said, maybe someone has another idea...

Comment: I see ı will wait for ideas

Comment: you could also move the low-poly faces where you see that it doesn't work